# mysql load data local infile adding quote mark

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I am using this query to import a text file into a MySQL table:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myfile.txt'
        INTO TABLE mytable 
        FIELDS TERMINATED by '\t'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
        (colA, colB, colC);
```

from a tab delimited file that looks like:

```
name1   name2  name3
```

but when it imports the last column gets enclosed in quotes:

```
name1   name2  "name3"
```

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

solution is to include the lines terminated by option '\r', i.e.

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

as this was missing a new line string was being added in the last column during import